# Batch execute command in separate running CMD window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to write a batch file script that can execute a text command in another CMD window that is already running. The secondary CMD window must not close afterwards, and it can be referenced by a window Title. There are a few 'cmd.exe' processes running in the environment and it would be ideal to have some kind of method to execute the command to the specific window by its title.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files don't have the ability to interact with different windows. For that, you'll need to use either [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx) or something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) / [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: Thank you for the links. This system is designed to be run automatically from a PHP script (hopefully using exec()). How would I acheive the same effect using the two given options (PowerShell / AutoIt)?

Comment: Start your "child" command windows using `cmd /k "title Foo1"` (change Foo1 as needed); next you'll need a helper script:find the window by titlefor PowerShell use FindWindow dll call (see the PowerShell script link), for AutoIt use `WinGetHandle()` from [AutoIt window functions](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm) to find the window by title; next in your helper script send the keystrokes + enter for the command you want run in that window